# Can anyone explain to me how to achieve this look? Looks 3d Extruded

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, text, 3d

[image]I am trying to create a graphic using a technique like this and I have tried 3d extrusion and get a super ugly result.  I am curious if anyone can help me understand how to get it in a color with the black outlines on the points of the extrusion.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your over thinking this a bit. all you really need to do is sraw lines out of same point over abd over again.

Comment: It is simply 1 point perspective.